# How to active on fucntion javascript but not only on function

Tags: javascript, php, html, native

but i want to ask. i have javascript code that only works on change when we input something. i want to this code to run also not when we want to input something, but when there's a value on it it also can run.

```
    $(function () {
    $('.unit,.qty').on('change', function () {
    var unit = $(this).hasClass('unit') ? $(this).val() : $(this).siblings('.unit').val();
    var qty = $(this).hasClass('qty') ? $(this).val() : $(this).siblings('.qty').val();
    unit = unit || 0;
    qty = qty || 0;
    var val = unit >= 1 && qty >= 1 ? parseFloat(unit * qty) : 0;
    $(this).siblings('.amount').val(val);
    var total = 0;
    var update = false;
    $('.amount').each(function () {
        val = parseFloat($(this).val()) | 0;
        total = val ? (parseFloat(total + val)) : total;
    });
    $('.result').val(total);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to make this run when the page loads?

Comment: yes for example , <input value="12000">, the number of value dosen't show. so i need to type it,

Comment: After you declared your function and hopefully inside a document.ready function add `$('.unit,.qty').trigger('change')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code in a browser, you can use the window object and listen to event 'load', then you can call your function when window is loaded.

```js
const yourFunction = (e) => {
  console.log(e)
}

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  yourFunction(event);
});
```